# replace word only if string contains - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

Need to replace the word "html" with "jpg" only in the lines that contain "_%7bwidth%7d"

Used `^(.*_%7bwidth%7d.*)html` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685633/how-to-find-and-replace-in-the-marked-lines-in-notepad?noredirect=1&lq=1 `^(.*XYZ.*)PROBLEM`, but it highlights (and thus replaces) the entire line, rather than just "html". I've also tried putting html in parenthesis (). How can I get it to target just the word "html" rather than the full line?

current:

```
`../../files/1/0400/8883/0101/products/81WG5qy3-VL._AC_SL1500_%7bwidth%7dxc3a8.html?v=1608528017`
```

expected result:

```
`../../files/1/0400/8883/0101/products/81WG5qy3-VL._AC_SL1500xc3a8.jpg?v=1608528017`
```

Comment: what is the `replace with` ? ... add that info to the question

Comment: please add few lines of the text you are processing... format it as code

Comment: _replace the word "html" with "jpg"._ So I suppose the `replace with` is `jpg` . .
Added the current & expected lines. thx

Comment: you have to reinsert the find text that is surrounded by brackets ... so the `replace with` should be `\1jpg`

Comment: Ok - I'm beginning to understand the syntax - thank you - that worked

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?_%7bwidth%7d.*?\Khtml\b`
- Replace with: `jpg`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
.+?                 # 1 or more any character but newline
_%7bwidth%7d        # string to be found
.*?                 # 0 or more any character but newline
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
html                # string to be replaced
\b                  # word boundary
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]